# R: Detect a "main" Path and remove or filter the GPS trace maybe using a kernel?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyr, r-raster, r-sf

Is there a way to filter out those parts which don't belong to the main path? As you can see in the picture i would like to remove the crossed out part while keeping the main path. I already tried using zoo/rolling median but without success. I thought i could use maybe a kernel of some sort for this task but im not sure. I also tried different smooth approaches / functions but those does not provided a desired outcome and rather made things worse.
Dist value in the data can be ignored.

One approach could be:

1. Take n previos points
2. get the mean / median bearing
3. compare bearing of n+1 point
4. if bearing is far to different from mean one of n points, discard the point.

So the mistake my path finding algo does is to go "forward" and then back the same way. This situation im trying to identify and filter out.

[image]

```
path<-structure(list(counter = 1:100, lon = c(11.83000844, 11.82986091, 
11.82975536, 11.82968137, 11.82966589, 11.83364579, 11.83346388, 
11.83479848, 11.83630055, 11.84026754, 11.84215965, 11.84530872, 
11.85369492, 11.85449806, 11.85479096, 11.85888555, 11.85908087, 
11.86262424, 11.86715538, 11.86814045, 11.86844252, 11.87138302, 
11.87579809, 11.87736704, 11.87819829, 11.88358436, 11.88923677, 
11.89024638, 11.89091832, 11.90027148, 11.9027736, 11.90408114, 
11.9063466, 11.9068819, 11.90833199, 11.91121547, 11.91204623, 
11.91386018, 11.91657306, 11.91708085, 11.91761264, 11.91204623, 
11.90833199, 11.90739525, 11.90583785, 11.904688, 11.90191917, 
11.90143671, 11.90027148, 11.89806126, 11.89694917, 11.89249712, 
11.88750445, 11.88720159, 11.88532786, 11.87757307, 11.87681905, 
11.86930751, 11.86872102, 11.8676844, 11.86696599, 11.86569006, 
11.85307297, 11.85078596, 11.85065013, 11.85055277, 11.85054529, 
11.85105901, 11.8513188, 11.85441234, 11.85771987, 11.85784653, 
11.85911367, 11.85937322, 11.85957177, 11.85964041, 11.85962915, 
11.8596438, 11.85976783, 11.86056853, 11.86078973, 11.86122148, 
11.86172538, 11.86227576, 11.86392935, 11.86563636, 11.86562302, 
11.86849157, 11.86885719, 11.86901696, 11.86930676, 11.87338922, 
11.87444184, 11.87391755, 11.87329231, 11.8723503, 11.87316759, 
11.87325551, 11.87332646, 11.87329074), lat = c(48.10980039, 
48.10954023, 48.10927434, 48.10891122, 48.10873965, 48.09824039, 
48.09526792, 48.0940306, 48.09328273, 48.09161348, 48.09097173, 
48.08975325, 48.08619985, 48.08594538, 48.08576984, 48.08370241, 
48.08237208, 48.08128785, 48.08204915, 48.08193609, 48.08186387, 
48.08102563, 48.07902278, 48.07827614, 48.07791392, 48.07583181, 
48.07435852, 48.07418376, 48.07408811, 48.07252594, 48.07207418, 
48.07174377, 48.07108668, 48.07094458, 48.07061937, 48.07033965, 
48.07033089, 48.07034706, 48.07025797, 48.07020637, 48.07014061, 
48.07033089, 48.07061937, 48.07081572, 48.07123129, 48.07156883, 
48.07224388, 48.07232886, 48.07252594, 48.07313464, 48.07346191, 
48.07389275, 48.0748072, 48.07488497, 48.07531827, 48.06876325, 
48.06880849, 48.06992189, 48.06935392, 48.0688597, 48.06872843, 
48.0682826, 48.06236784, 48.06083756, 48.06031525, 48.06007589, 
48.05979028, 48.05819348, 48.05773109, 48.05523588, 48.05084893, 
48.0502925, 48.04750087, 48.0471574, 48.04655424, 48.04615637, 
48.04573796, 48.03988503, 48.03985935, 48.03986151, 48.03984645, 
48.0397989, 48.03966795, 48.03925767, 48.03841738, 48.03701502, 
48.03658961, 48.03417456, 48.03394195, 48.03386125, 48.03372952, 
48.03236277, 48.03045774, 48.02935764, 48.02770804, 48.0262546, 
48.02391112, 48.02376389, 48.02361916, 48.02295931), dist = c(16.5491019417617, 
12.387608371535, 13.7541383821868, 33.4916122880205, 6.9703128008864, 
30.9036305788955, 8.61214448946505, 25.0174570393888, 37.1966950033338, 
114.428731827878, 42.6981252797486, 35.484064302826, 46.6949888899517, 
29.3780621124218, 11.3743525290235, 37.7195808156292, 62.6333126726666, 
28.4692721123006, 17.0298455473048, 14.3098664643564, 17.7499631308564, 
87.1393427315571, 60.3089055364667, 41.7849043662927, 87.2691684053224, 
97.1454278187317, 53.9239973250175, 53.8018772046333, 57.751515546603, 
27.3798478555643, 30.6642975040561, 48.4553170757953, 41.9759520786297, 
33.3880134641802, 37.3807049759314, 49.8823206292369, 49.7792541871492, 
61.821997105488, 40.2477260156321, 32.2363477179296, 43.918067054065, 
89.6254564762497, 35.5927710501446, 27.6333379571774, 42.0554883840467, 
45.4018421835631, 4.07647329598549, 52.945234942045, 44.2345694983538, 
63.8855719530995, 37.3036925262838, 11.4985551858961, 47.6500054672646, 
12.488428646998, 13.7372221770588, 24.4479793264376, 71.2384899552303, 
52.9595905197645, 16.8213670893537, 37.0777367654005, 20.1344312201034, 
24.7504557199489, 15.9504355215393, 4.4986704990778, 17.4471004003001, 
9.04823098759565, 25.684547529165, 15.2396067965458, 13.9748972112566, 
88.9846859415509, 15.1658523003296, 18.6262158018174, 8.95876566894735, 
19.8247489326594, 20.4813444727095, 23.6721190072342, 14.4891642200285, 
10.6402985988761, 10.1346051623741, 15.3824252473173, 17.5975390671566, 
15.758052106193, 11.4810033780958, 25.1035007014738, 21.3402595089137, 
28.5373345425722, 11.3907620234039, 7.18155005801645, 13.5078761535753, 
14.0009018934227, 4.09891462242866, 9.47515101787348, 10.755798004242, 
23.9344946865876, 36.4670348302756, 5.53642050027254, 18.2898185695699, 
17.1906059877831, 17.5321948763862, 16.2784860139608)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

****UPDATE 09.10.2020****

Thank you so much for your proposals of solution. Every solution was very interesting and if i could i would accept all of them.

**Solution Nr1 by ekoam**
I really like that it only depends on base packages within R! It's an interesting approach yet I have to optimize it to be able to apply it to the whole dataset. I would divide the whole path based on bearing change and use this algo on filter separate parts and connect them together. If I would go only for speed, this would be an approach I would have chosen.!

**Solution Nr2 by mrhellmann**
It's a very interesting approach that depends on very fresh specialized packages. It also involves a bit more computation then other 2 and produces not so smooth result in compairesement to other 2. I will play around with those packages and I think there is a lot of potential! I played with the value of K but was not able to remove the "tail" so to say that i wanted to remove accourding to the drawing.

**Solution Nr3 by BrianLang**
This solution produced the best result right away on the whole dataset with a sudden change in path. Its a bit heavy regarding CPU consumption but it works the best right out of the box so to say and that is why I would choose this solution as an answer to this question.

Thank you very much i really appreciate all the time you all invested in answering this question.

**Update 09.10.2020 15:19**
Its basically neck a neck between the proposal from **mrhellmann** and **BrianLang**
The propsal from **mrhellmann** produces lightly smother graph since it lets other points be.
The current difference is 7 points.

[image]
In comparison the proposal form **BrianLang**
[image]

And this is how the whole track looks without optimization:
[image]

The solution provided by **mrhellmann** requiers around 6 sec to run on 637 points. The solution provided by **BrianLang** runs in 6 sec also.
So now there is only difference in use of packages and possibilty for optimization.

Comment: Do you have any data we can use?

Comment: I added an example dataset.

Comment: What counts as 'the main path'? In this case you clearly want to remove the part where it just goes along the road and back again, but what about more general cases? What if it had been a small loop instead?

Comment: Main path would be a path with bigger amounts of points. Looping would be not a problem as long as points in a loop otweight others  points by count in a "window" so to say.

Comment: What is series 'dist' in your data?  Are you trying to apply some logic/rules to this variable to isolate points outside the 'main path'?     How do we know that the actual path does not include those points circled with X-mark -- it's a possibility that the road may be winding and goes East and then come back West?

Comment: Dist can be ignored. Its used for a different purpose.  I think it could be possible to identify a main path based on n previous points and detect a general vector of movement so to say. Is it maybe possible if there is an algorithm to determine the vector of movement to adjust the amount of detection so to say.

Comment: Maybe a main path could be identified based on average bearing of n previous points?

Comment: Maybe it help: https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2019/09/26/spatial-networks.html

Comment: I think this r-spatial linked from @CarlosEduardoLagosta would help. Doing this without any knowledge of the possible paths you are following seems like an impossible task without any metrics, but if you were to map your points onto the road network, you could then ask for the shortest path between your starting and stopping point, while still keeping to the waypoints you provide as best as possible.

Comment: Needs more definition about what is a main path. How much of a turn radius is acceptable? Is it fine as long as it's not back tracking? Without some definition or more examples, there is no answer.

Comment: Hi Roger, every radius is fine as long there is no backtracking. So the mistake my path finding algo does is to go "forward" and then back the same way. This situation im trying to identify and filter out.

Comment: Could'nt you just remove all the points between two visits at the same point ?

Comment: How would i recognise the points to be removed?

Comment: I imagine you (not exactly you, of course .. ) are going from a place A to a place B, and your path give you the ordered points to visit .. it isn't the case ?

Comment: Yes that's true but all the information i have is a counter and gps position.

Comment: With this, I remove a part of the path .. but not sure it will satisfy you .. `path[, latlon := paste0(as.character(lat),as.character(lon))]
path[, count := seq(.N), by = latlon]
path2 <-  path[counter >= path[latlon %in% path[count == 2, latlon], max(counter)]
               | counter < path[latlon %in% path[count == 2, latlon], min(counter)]]`

Comment: Obviously it will not work if you have two disjoint part of unwanted path ... but you may adapt it for those more complex cases

Comment: could you please post it as an possible answer?

Comment: MrSmithGoesToWashington sadly it creates a huge gap sadly on a path. Out of 643 points it removes 390 points but there are only around 3 path$count>1 accurences. Maybe there is some logical error with your code?

Comment: @Andreas Smooth, fast, complete, and packages used. Prioritizing would help. Is it ok to leave out points& how many? Is a line better or worse than original points, or are sampled points along the path ok? Should it be smoothed or stick to original path? The answers can be optimized, but constraints are needed.

Comment: Sorry i just nedded to find a way to compare the proposals since they produce similar results now. If you can see at the first comments beneatht the question; it was like "its impossible.." and now there are 3 great approaches. I dont mean any disrespect. There are just 2 constrains: remove points as best as possible that are lead to wrong part of the path (back an forth) and performance. Thats it. Im really thankfull for all the time you took to provide me help. If its possible to bring down the run time that would be absolutely awesome!

Comment: @Andreas No worries, I didn't intend to sound upset.  My answer below can be modified in a few places to be faster, smoother, etc.  As it is, it has complete coverage of the original points and is likely to work on many sets of similar data, but may be a little slow. I was asking just to be able to improve the answer.

Comment: I would focus on performance now. Your approach works great! if you could shave off a couple of seconds of run time that would be perfect!

Comment: @Andreas : I mean, whereever you are wandering between to stay at the same point, (you may wander through the same points or not) you can remove this part of your path, because you reach the point the first time from A and leave it the second time to reach B .. so that a point is visited only once does not mean it is a usefull point ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edits below one for a more correct & complete answer, the other for a faster one.

This solution works for this case, but I'm not sure it will work in cases that aren't similarly shaped.  There are a few parameters that can be adjusted that might find better results.  It relies heavily on the `sf` package and classes.

The code below will:

- Start with all the points as an `sf` object
- Connect each to (an adjustable) number of its nearest neighbors
- Remove the connections that are too far off the path
- Create a network
- Find the shortest path (which will have too few points from the original data)
- Get the missing points back

```
libary(sf)
library(tidyverse) ## <- heavy, but it's easy to load the whole thing
library(tidygraph) ##  I'm not sure this was needed
library(nngeo)
library(sfnetworks) ## https://github.com/luukvdmeer/sfnetworks


path_sf <- st_as_sf(path, coords = c('lon', 'lat')

# create a buffer around a connected line of our points.
#  used later to filter out unwanted edges of graph
path_buffer <- 
  path_sf %>%
   st_combine() %>%
   st_cast('MULTILINESTRING') %>%
   st_buffer(dist = .001)         ## dist = arg will depend on projection CRS.


# Connect each point to its 20 nearest neighbors,
#  probably overkill, but it works here.  Problems occur when points on the path
#  have very uneven spacing. A workaround would be to st_sample a linestring of the path
connected20 <- st_connect(path_sf, path_sf,
                          ids = st_nn(path_sf, path_sf, k = 20))
```

What we have so far:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = path_sf) + 
  geom_sf(data = path_buffer, color = 'green', alpha = .1) +
  geom_sf(data = connected20, alpha = .1)
```

[image: Points, Buffer & Connections]

Now we need to get rid of the connections outside `path_buffer`.

```
# Remove unwanted edges outside the buffer
edges <- connected20[st_within(connected20,
                               path_buffer,
                               sparse = F),] %>%
  st_as_sf()
```

`ggplot(edges) + geom_sf(alpha = .2) + theme_void()`

[image: Clipped edges]

```
## Create a network from the edges
net <- as_sfnetwork(edges, directed = T) ########## directed?

## Use network to find shortest path from the first point to the last. 
## This will exclude some original points,
##  we'll get them back soon.
shortest_path <- st_shortest_paths(net,
                                   path_sf[1,],
                                   path_sf[nrow(path_sf),])

# Probably close to the shortest path, the turn looks long
short_ish <- path_sf[shortest_path$vpath[[1]],]
```

The plot of `short_ish` shows that some points are probably missing:

[image]

```
# Use this to regain all points on the shortest path
short_buffer <- short_ish %>%
  st_combine() %>%
  st_cast('LINESTRING') %>%
  st_buffer(dist = .001)

short_all <- path_sf[st_within(path_sf, short_buffer, sparse = F), ]
```

Almost all the points on (what may be) the shortest path:

[image]

Adjusting buffer distances `dist`, and number of nearest neighbors `k = 20` might give you a better result.  For some reason this misses a couple of points just south of the fork, and might travel too far east at the fork. The nearest neighbors function can also return distances.  Removing connections longer than the greatest distance between neighboring points would help.

**Edit**:

Code below should get a better track after running code above.  Image includes original track, shortest path, all points along the shortest track, and the buffer to obtain those points.  Start point in green, end point in red.

```
## Path buffer as above, dist = .002 instead of .001
path_buffer <- 
  path_sf %>%
  st_combine() %>%
  st_cast('MULTILINESTRING') %>%
  st_buffer(dist = .002)        

### Starting point, 1st point of data
p1 <- net %>% activate('nodes') %>%
  st_as_sf() %>% slice(1)

### Ending point, last point of data
p2 <- net %>% activate('nodes') %>%
  st_as_sf() %>% tail(1)

# New short path
shortest_path2 <- net %>% 
  convert(to_spatial_shortest_paths, p1, p2)
# Buffer again to get all points from original
shortest_path_buffer <- shortest_path2 %>%
  activate(edges) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  st_cast('MULTILINESTRING') %>%
  st_combine() %>%
  st_buffer(dist = .0018)

# Shortest path, using all points from original data
all_points_short_path <- path_sf[st_within(path_sf, shortest_path_buffer, sparse = F),]

# Plotting
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = p1, size = 4, color = 'green') + 
  geom_sf(data = p2, size = 4, color = 'red') + 
  geom_sf(data = path_sf, color = 'black', alpha = .2) + 
  geom_sf(data = activate(shortest_path2, 'edges') %>% st_as_sf(), color = 'orange', alhpa = .4) + 
  geom_sf(data = shortest_path_buffer, fill = 'blue', alpha = .2) + 
  geom_sf(data = all_points_short_path, color = 'orange', alpha = .4) +
  theme_void()
```

[image: Final plot, all included]

**Edit 2**
Probably faster, though hard to tell how much with a small dataset.  Also, less likely to include all correct points. Misses a few points from original data.

```
path_sf <- st_as_sf(path, coords = c('lon', 'lat'))


# Higher density is slower, but more complete. 
# Higher k will be fooled by winding paths as incorrect edges aren't buffered out
# in the interest of speed.
density = 200
k = 4
  
start <- path_sf[1, ] %>% st_geometry()
end <- path_sf[dim(path_sf)[1],] %>% st_geometry()

path_sf_samp <- path_sf %>%
  st_combine() %>%
  st_cast('LINESTRING') %>%
  st_line_sample(density = density) %>%
  st_cast('POINT') %>%
  st_union(start) %>%
  st_union(end) %>%
  st_cast('POINT')%>%
  st_as_sf()

connected3 <- st_connect(path_sf_samp, path_sf_samp,
                          ids = st_nn(path_sf_samp, path_sf_samp, k = k))

edges <- connected3 %>%
  st_as_sf()

net <- as_sfnetwork(edges, directed = F) ########## directed?

shortest_path <- net %>% 
  convert(to_spatial_shortest_paths, start, end)

shortest_path_buffer <- shortest_path %>%
  activate(edges) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  st_cast('MULTILINESTRING') %>%
  st_combine() %>%
  st_buffer(dist = .0018)

all_points_short_path <- path_sf[st_within(path_sf, shortest_path_buffer, sparse = F),]


ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = path_sf, color = 'black', alpha = .2) + 
  geom_sf(data = activate(shortest_path, 'edges') %>% st_as_sf(), color = 'orange', alpha = .4) + 
  geom_sf(data = shortest_path_buffer, fill = 'blue', alpha = .2) + 
  geom_sf(data = all_points_short_path, color = 'orange', alpha = .4) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test it on the whole dataset in couple of hours and get back to you with a result. Im very excited to see how this approach will work on different situations! Thank you!

Comment: @Andreas I'll edit the post with an update that fixes the problems within the hour.

Comment: Thank you very much! Im excited to see the difference.

Comment: i get this error: > # New short path
> shortest_path2 <- net %>% 
+   convert(to_spatial_shortest_paths, p1, p2)
Warnmeldung:
In (function (graph, from, to = V(graph), mode = c("out", "all",  :
  At structural_properties.c:745 :Couldn't reach some vertices

Comment: found my mistake

Comment: please see my eddit for results.

Comment: @Andreas Edit 2 should be faster, though less complete & more easily fooled by winding paths.  Adjust `density` and `k` at the top of the code as necessary.

Comment: lol i say faster 0.519 sec elapsed. I say you win. No degredation as i see it otherwise.

Comment: It took a while, but was an interesting problem.  Thanks & good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! & Help!

Answer (score 4):

I will make an attempt to answer this question. Here I am using a naive algorithm. Hopefully, other people can propose solutions better than this one.

I guess we can assume that the starting and ending points of your GPS trace are always on the so-called "main path". If this assumption is valid, then we can draw a line between these two points and use that as the reference. Call this the **reference line**.

The algorithm is:

1. For each point *i* of that trace, calculate the distance from the point to the reference line. Call this distance ***d<sub>i</sub>***.
2. Tabulate the empirical distribution of all *d<sub>i</sub>* s and select only those points with *d<sub>i</sub>* below a specific quantile of that distribution. Call this quantile the **threshold**. Using a higher threshold is logically equivalent to selecting more points.
3. The **main path** is, therefore, the route defined by those selected points.

To calculate *d<sub>i</sub>*, I use the following formula from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#:%7E:text=The%20distance%20from%20%28x0,along%20a%20horizontal%20line%20segment.) Wikipedia webpage:

[image: formula]

The code is

```
distan <- function(lon, lat) {
  x1 <- lon[[1L]]; y1 <- lat[[1L]]
  x2 <- tail(lon, 1L); y2 <- tail(lat, 1L)
  dy <- y2 - y1; dx <- x2 - x1
  abs(dy * lon - dx * lat + x2 * y1 - y2 * x1) / sqrt(dy * dy + dx * dx)
}

path_filter <- function(lon, lat, threshold = 0.6) {
  d <- distan(lon, lat)
  th <- quantile(d, threshold, na.rm = TRUE)
  d <= th
}
```

The `path_filter` function returns a logical vector of the same length as the input vector(s), so you can use it like this (assume that `path` is a `data.table`):

```
path[path_filter(lon, lat, 0.6), ]
```

Now let's see the resultant main paths for different thresholds. I use the following code to plot figures for thresholds 0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

map <- ne_countries(scale = "small", returnclass = "sf")

df <- 
  path %>% 
  expand(threshold = 0:10 / 10, nesting(counter, lon, lat)) %>% 
  group_by(threshold) %>% 
  filter(path_filter(lon, lat, threshold)) %>% 
  mutate(threshold = paste0("threshold = ", threshold))

ggplot(map) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = threshold), size = 0.01, data = df) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = range(df$lon), ylim = range(df$lat)) + 
  facet_wrap(vars(threshold), ncol = 4L) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .5))
```

The plots are:

[image]

Indeed, a higher threshold gives you more points. For your specific case, I guess you would like to use a threshold of about 0.6?

Comment: Wow this is great! Yes threshold of 0.6 seems good! Im ok with a small deviation from the path. I will try this solution on whole dataset in the morning. Thank you very much! It would be interesting to see how this algorithm will react to change of direction:

Comment: It would be interesting to see how this algorithm will react to change of direction. I think i would have to devide the main path into parts based on mean bearing. Then apply this algorithm to each part.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've thought about bearings and difference in bearings a bit and have created an approach which simply considers the angle between the bearing of line `(i, i+1)` and the bearing of line `(i+1, i+2)`.
If the angle between these two bearings is greater than some threshold, we delete points `i` and `i+1`.

[image: filtered track]

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(geosphere)

## This function calculates the difference between two bearings
angle_diff <- function(theta1, theta2){
 theta <- abs(theta1 - theta2) %% 360 
 return(ifelse(theta > 180, 360 - theta, theta))
}

## This function removes points (i, i + 1) if the bearing difference 
## between (i, i+1) and (i+1, i+2) is larger than angle 
filter_function <- function(data, angle){
 data %>% ungroup() %>% 
  (function(X)X %>% 
    slice(-(X %>% 
             filter(bearing_diff > angle)  %>%
             select(counter, counter_2) %>%
             unlist()))) 
}


## This function calculates the bearing of the line (i, i+1)
## It also handles the iteration needed in the while-loop
calc_bearing <- function(data, lead_counter = TRUE){
 data %>% 
  mutate(counter = 1:n(),
         lat2 = lead(lat), 
         lon2 = lead(lon),
         counter_2 = lead(counter)) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(bearing = geosphere::bearing(p1 = c(lat, lon),
                                      p2 = c(lat2, lon2))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(bearing_diff = angle_diff(bearing, lead(bearing)))
}

## this is our max angle
max_angle = 100

## Here is our while loop which cycles though the path,
## removing pairs of points (i, i+1) which have "inconsistent" 
## bearings. 
filtered <- 
 path %>%
 as_tibble() %>% 
 calc_bearing() %>%
 (function(X){
  while(any(X$bearing_diff > max_angle) &
        !is.na(any(X$bearing_diff > max_angle))){
   X <- X %>% 
    filter_function(angle = max_angle) %>%
    calc_bearing()
  }
  X
 })

## Here we plot the new track
ggplot(filtered, aes(lon, lat)) +
 geom_point() +
 coord_map()
```

Comment: this works actually suprisingly well! Thank you very much! i will just compare it to other proposals in regarding speed and so on.

Comment: I would guess that it's less sensitive to paths that deviate severely from a reference line between the starting and end point. For certain types of paths (out and back runs, obviously) my approach will return an empty list of points and this is similar for the reference line approach.  However, the nearest-neighbor approach would be fine for out-and-back tracks.

Comment: the approach you provided is the best one yet and it works on every path i currently tried right out of the box. The Approach by @ekoam is the fastest one in regarding computation but i need to split the path in parts and calculate bearing for those parts and apply this approach to parts of the path. I think your approach can be speed up if i get rid of a while loop.

Comment: yeah i think we lose something by recalculating the bearing differences for *the entire* set of pairs. doing it more cleverly could involve looking at which points were removed and recalculating just there.

Comment: Or some how vectorize the loop. Split it in parts.

Comment: The slowest thing there is certainly the calculation of the bearing and the angle between bearings. if you did those calculations only when needed you could take the number of time you calculate them from `n*k` times to `n + k` times, with `k` being the iterations needed. I expect that changing it from a `while` loop will take a lot more time than anything you could save. switching to data.tables and their implementations could help, but i'm unfamiliar with how to do that.

Comment: please see my eddit for results.

Answer (score 1):

Just assuming you can remove points between to visits to the same points ..
Here it goes :

```
setDT(path)
path[, latlon := paste0(as.character(lat),as.character(lon))]
path[, count := seq(.N), by = latlon]
to_remove  <-  path[latlon %in% path[count == 2, latlon], .(M = max(counter), 
                        m = min(counter)),
                    by = latlon ]
path2 <- path[!counter %in% unique(to_remove[, .(points =  m:M), by = 1:length(to_remove)][, points])]
```

Comment: do i understand your approach correctly: you are looking for the same point that was visited twice?

Comment: The problem i see here: GPS fluctuates within couple of meters. So hitting same point twice is a bit unsafe assumption.

Comment: I agree whtih your point. What I don't understood in your matter is how do you know that you can go from a point to another or not ... my approach states that you can't make a move that was not previously already in the path ..